# How to Get Subcategories by category name in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the all subcategories by parent category name here is my current code

```
<?php
//get all categories then display all posts in each term
$taxonomy = 'category';
$param_type = 'category__in';
$term_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
);

$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
if ($terms) {
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args=array(

      "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),

      'post_type' => 'portfolio',
      'category_name'    => 'web-design',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 6,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      );
    $my_query = null;

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  ?>
```

as you can see I am  using portfolio as custom post type  and web-design as a parent category name, I want to get all subcategories of parent category i.e web-design